# Spreading water evenly between connected vessels are differing heights and distances

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, flow, home-experiment

[image]

Working on a self watering planter and am having trouble calculating the way this water would spread between connected vessels. The top vessel will connect to the other vessels with small aquarium tubing, what would the calculations I need to make be in order to get the water spreading evenly? I'm guessing I would need different sized tubes or something like that. Any suggestions?

[image: Image of the water containers]

Comment: Just to warn you, this may get closed for being an engineering question.